# JQuery Knockout - Assign json data to select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have a simple select dropdown I would like to populate from json data. When I hardcoded the json data as embedded javascript, it works, but when I try to use JQuery's getJSON callback to retrieve the data, it does not populate the select. I've checked that the web url works and returns proper json result, I believe I'm not calling it in the right order or something.

I've tried searching and many give examples which I tried, e.g. assigning the json result to a global variable.

HTML below:

```
<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name'"></select>
```

JS (which works with embedded jsondata) below:

```
var jsdata = [{"id":1,"name":"Fruits","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Banana","price":0.99,"catid":1},{"id":2,"name":"Apple","price":0.49,"catid":1},{"id":3,"name":"Orange","price":0.69,"catid":1}]},{"id":2,"name":"Beverage","products":[{"id":4,"name":"Coca Cola","price":1.99,"catid":2},{"id":5,"name":"Dr. Pepper","price":1.89,"catid":2},{"id":6,"name":"Sprite","price":1.79,"catid":2},{"id":7,"name":"Mountain Dew","price":1.69,"catid":2},{"id":8,"name":"7-Up","price":1.59,"catid":2}]},
              {"id":3,"name":"test","products":[]}];

var ViewModel = function (js) {
        var self = this;
        self.json = js;
        self.options = ko.toJS(js);      
}    
var vm = new ViewModel(jsdata);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The jsfiddler is @  http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/7vcqX/#

Tried using getJSON instead but didn't work:

```
$.getJSON("url-to-data", null, function(data) {       
   var ViewModel = function (js) {
        var self = this;
        self.json = js;
        self.options = ko.toJS(js);      
   }    
   var vm = new ViewModel(data);
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Also tried:

```
var globaljson;
$.getJSON("url-to-data", null, function(data) {       
   globaljson = data;
});

var ViewModel = function (js) {
        var self = this;
        self.json = js;
        self.options = ko.toJS(js);      
   }    
   var vm = new ViewModel(globaljson);
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Inside getJSON callback does data contain desired json? BTW, you can skip second parameter (null) in getJSON if you have no data to transfer.

Comment: Yes the url does return the right results, like the hardcoded json data.

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle to use getJSON from fake service - http://jsfiddle.net/7vcqX/25/. It works fine, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Main difference I am seeing is the data. The json data I have is not in key/value format, but rather has properties like id and name e.g. : var jsdata = [{"id":1,"name":"Fruits","products":[],              {"id":3,"name":"Beverage","products":[]}];

Comment: Should it be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7vcqX/26/?

Comment: @Ilya: Yes that's what I want to achieve, and it works when the json data is embedded, but I can't get it to work when a web url returns the data from getJSON.

Comment: @Ilya: Cool, this solution seems to work, I think one of the main issues when I tested on jsfiddler is that selecting Knockout 3.0.0 as the Framework isn't sufficient. I noticed you added jquery libraries as an External Resource. And i used my local web url in the getJSON which also didn't work and seems to work now that I also set it as an External Resource. Testing abit more now.

Comment: Nice. I've added my solution as an answer. Please accept it, if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a bit different code to create your observable array:

```
$.getJSON('your url', function(data) {
    var ViewModel = function(js) {
        var self = this;
        self.json = js;
        self.options = ko.observableArray($.map(js, function(item) { return { name: item.name, value: item.id } }));
    };
    var vm = new ViewModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7vcqX/26/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), you should use an array as options for a `select`. So try something like:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {       
   var ViewModel = function (options) {
        var self = this;
        self.options = ko.observableArray($.map(options, function(key, value) { return { name: value, value: key } }));
   }    
   var vm = new ViewModel(data);
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Comment: I tried it in the jsfiddler, also didn't work. I believe you don't necessarily have to return an array, as it works when the json data is directly assigned as a variable. Now what is required is for the data to be retrieved using ajax, the data is returned and I can see it in the network data in developer mode, but the select is not populated.